# Program which Compile by Code::Block plus MinGW, but Using Standard Windows Library?

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

everyone.

I am a newer for c++, and I had some experience on c#. I want to create a pure c++ developing environment, and using the standard c++ library. My operation system is Windows.

I choose code::block+MinGW to build a pure developing environment on Windows. I directly choose Code::Block installation packet which integrate MinGW. Then I began to develop my first learning project. And In this project, I used the function "stat" to get file information from standard library. And I passed the compile. But during operation this program, I checked the "Call Stack". And found the function "stat" called from file "C:\WINDOWS\system32\msvcrt.dll". And I checked this dll from internet, and found this file is a microsoft windows library file. So it obviously, this dll file don't have the function "stat", but have the function "_stat".

So how do I solve this problem? I want to use the standard c++ library, not the microsoft windows library. Because later, I want to move this project to linux environment. So overall, how do I build the developing environment to satisfy my requirement.

Comment: `stat` is a unix system call and I dont think you can use it like this on windows.

Comment: There are a handful of cross-platform C++ libraries out there, such as Boost and Qt.  if you're going to be doing cross-platform work, I'd suggest starting with them and working from there.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? You say that your program compiles and links with a call to `stat()` - I can do this as well with MinGW or MSVC (for simple uses of `stat()`) and the program runs just fine.

Comment: Hi, Michael. In fact, you checked in MinGW's instruction in its home page. It said that "MinGW provides a complete Open Source programming tool set which is suitable for the development of native MS-Windows applications". So it seems that MinGW is only for Windows system. And function "stat" is a unix system call (as NeonGlow said). So of course the program compiled by MinGW can't use unix system function, ex. stat. Am I understanding right?

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the windows system libraries if you're building for Windows. You simply link one or the other depending on the target system. The libraries merely provide the underlying implementation, which is different from one OS to the next.

In your specific example, stat is a function defined by standard system headers, but its underlying implementation will vary from system to system. It's possible that the entire function is pulled from msvcrt, but my guess is that msvcrt happens to implement a companion function which deals with all the system-specific stuff.